# Make div fill the entire screen in React

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this simple react code with css.

My problem is that the `.loginFundo` div is not taking the entire screen, a large part of the screen is left blank, how can I solve this?

```js
import './index.css'

export function Login(){
    return (
        <div className='loginFundo'>
            <div className='loginBase'>
                <div className='loginImage'>
                    image
                </div>

                <div className='loginInputs'>
                    inputs
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.loginFundo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #CEE9EA;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.loginBase {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code in plain HTML / CSS and .loginFundo **IS** taking up 100% width and 100% height of the body. It's doing exactly what you want (in Chrome, Firefox & Safari)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.loginFundo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #CEE9EA;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.loginBase {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginFundo">
    <div class="loginBase">
        <div class="loginImage">
            image
        </div>

        <div class="loginInputs">
            inputs
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @jessman5, thanks for the help, it works the way I expected.